# what does #[account(mut)] do in solana?

Tags: account, initialize

I know what procedural macros are. They are like decorators, they add new functionality or properties into the decorated code.

```
#[account(init,payer=user,space=9000)]
pub base_account:Account<'info,BaseAccount>,
```

I can understand above code that is initializing a new account. (Although I don't know what exactly the account do)

However, I do not understand this:

```
#[account(mut)]
pub user:Signer<'info>,
```

I cannot interpret anything and `mut` is extra confusing.

Answer (score 4):

`mut` is one of many constraints that go with the `#[account()]` attribute. It specifies that the instruction be allowed to modify the account's data. If an account isn't given the `mut` attribute in a validator then it won't be modifiable in the instruction, either to change its custom data or token balance. Here it's used because the `user` account pays for the initialization of `base_account`

Here's a full list of anchor_lang's [constraints.](https://docs.rs/anchor-lang/latest/anchor_lang/derive.Accounts.html)

Comment: Nice, I would like to add that the reasoning behind having `mut` and `non-mut` accounts, is a hint for Solana to know which accounts can be processed in parallel. If something is read only there is no need of mutexes etc.. And as to why a `payer` is mut as Ademola said it's because your `user` account is the payer and so its lamports field need to be mutable.